# SQLite exception no such table: Token

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin

I ran into an issue after finally getting my API call to work where it gives me the following exception

```
Unhandled Exception:

SQLite.SQLiteException: no such table: Token occurred
```

I have this class here

```
 public class Token
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string accessToken { get; set; }
        public string errorDescription { get; set; }
        public DateTime expireDate { get; set; }
        public int expireIn { get; set; }

        public Token() { }
    }
```

here is my ios sqlite class for ios

```
public class SQLite_iOS : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_iOS() { }
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection()
        {
            var dbName = "mydb.db3";
            var documentPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var libraryPath = Path.Combine(documentPath, "..", "Library");
            var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, dbName);
            var connection = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

here is my Api call

```
public async Task<string> LoginAsync(string email, string password)
        {

            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            var tokenInfo = new Token();
            var keyValues = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("email", email),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("password", password),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "password")
            };

            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://myurl/v1/auth/login");

            request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(keyValues);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            JObject jwtDynamic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(content);

            var accessTokenExpiration = jwtDynamic.Value<DateTime>(".expires");
            var accessToken = jwtDynamic.Value<string>("token");


            //Settings.AccessTokenExpirationDate = accessTokenExpiration;

            Debug.WriteLine(accessTokenExpiration);

            Debug.WriteLine(content);

            tokenInfo = new Token();
            tokenInfo.accessToken = "accessToken";
            db.Insert(tokenInfo);
            return accessToken;

        }
```

I have been learning this as I go, and have learned a lot, but it's all new to me right now. Thanks for the help

Comment: `connection.CreateTable<Token>();` https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#synchronous-api

Comment: this did it, Thanks! I can't believe I forgot about that!